# How to use a custom volume bootstrap image in vscode remote for containers when cloning a repository into a volume?

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-volume, vscode-devcontainer

When [cloning a repository into a volume with the vscode remote extension for containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-open-a-git-repository-or-github-pr-in-an-isolated-container-volume), an Alpine linux is downloaded from `docker.io` to bootstrap the volume (initially). This is only used to create the volume. The image which is then used for my application is the correct one I specified in the Dockerfile (not alpine).

How can I set a custom bootstrap image for bootstrapping the volume? The main reason for this is the security aspect: Only internal images should be used.

**Edit**: It seems that the `bootstrap.Dockerfile` can be manually changed in the extension's folder (`<user-folder>/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-<version>/scripts/volumeBootstrap.Dockerfile`), but this is not an appropriate solution. How can this file path be specified in e.g. the `devcontainer.json` or somewhere else?

Comment: Do you mean the repo you're cloning already has the `devcontainer.json` which is configured to use the Alpine image? Do you control that repo?

Comment: @MaxIvanov Hi Max, actually I would like to set another image for bootstrapping the Docker volume (i.e. an internal, scanned version of e.g. alpine linux). The image I specified is then correctly loaded afterwards.

Comment: The information in the Edit was very valuable for me to make this happen at all.  I agree this needs to be able to be specified in devcontainer.json.  For my use, I needed to bootstrap the container on an off-network computer.  I'm going to explore what it would take to add this to devcontainer.json